# removing extra stuffs from content creation page (Drupal 6.x)

Tags: drupal, forms, controls

Drupal 6.x

How do I remove collapsible frames - "Authoring information","Revision information", "Publishing Options" - from content creation page? For what is worth, I'm logging in as a regular user and I don't want these controls to be presented to regular users. 
P.S : I also like to remove save/preview buttons as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'administer nodes' permission deals with most of those, and for anything that's left, an easy point and click interface is provided by the [FormFilter](http://drupal.org/project/formfilter) module.

Removing the 'save' button, though, might prove a bit self-defeating.

For more control, get acquainted with the [FormAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6) and [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter).

Comment: Good answer !
I have found FormFilter as very useful in a similar task

Comment: I should have been more clear when I said I wanted to remove save button. What I wanted to do is, to change the "save" label to something I want but, as I don't know how to, I was thinking to remove it and replace the new button with the label I like.

I'll look into Formfilter module and get back to u in this regard.

Thanks a bunch for your reply.

Comment: Nice module for sites where you don't need to create a custom module for this kind of stuff. I'll use it on a site I'm working on right now :-) Andrew: To change Save button use form alter or string overrides http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Panels to change the presentation of the node add/edit forms.

Comment: Ok I'll look into that as well and see which one(Form Filter) works the best. Thanks.